# Comments same size/format as posts

Tags: discussion, design, style

I noticed with the new design the type for comments is the same size and format as the type for questions and answers. On other StackExchange sites the comments are slightly smaller visually distinguishing them as meta-content that is less important than the main content in the questions and answers.

Is this different approach intentional? Can we change the comments to be smaller like on other StackExchange sites?

Answer (score 4):

This was intentional. I felt a smaller text fits the apple theme better. It makes the site a bit airier. Originally I had planned for the Question/Answer text even smaller(12px) to be consistent with the official [Apple forum](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2741010&tstart=0). However I felt it was a bit too small, so I went with 13 pixels instead. If I had followed the convention you stated, that'd make the comment text too small to read IMO. I feel the current white background makes the comment text distinguishable enough. Another factor is, unlike the other SE sites, this site's question and answer(s) have their own colored block. So it's easier to scan.

Of course the new design has only gone live for a few days, it may take a bit to get used to the new design.

Comment: I don't see a colored block for the comments. For me the indentation isn't enough to offset them as comments and it can be confusing.

Comment: Jin, can you revisit this with the new Lion inspired theming? While I agreed with you before, white boxes on white background doesn't leave much distinction anymore.

Comment: @cabbey they look the same size to me now?

Comment: @Jeff, Sorry, I wasn't clear. I was talking about the colors... not the size. Specifically "Another factor is, unlike the other SE sites, this site's question and answer(s) have their own colored block. So it's easier to scan." that statement was used to justify the fonts being the same size, but it's no longer true with the new Lion inspired style.

Answer (score 1):

I know what you're saying. I guess the comments are visually distinguished by a different colored background and a little bit different formatting (including being indented into the post).

Overall they could make it a little more clear, but I think the system does them justice as it is.

Comment: For me the background of the post and the comments are both white. Are they supposed to be a different color? To me it isn't clear at all.